# Closest match per group with sqlite3 in python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I asked preciously how to find closest match, but I later I realized that sql-server `ROW_NUMBER` and `PARTITION BY` is not implemented in sqlite3 in python script.

Here is what I am trying to do:

I have table that looks similar to this:

```
Motor MotorType CalibrationValueX CalibrationValueY
A     Car       1.2343            2.33343
B     Boat      1.2455            2.55434
B1    Boat      1.4554            2.11211
C     Car       1.4323            4.56555
D     Car       1.533             4.6666
..... 500 entries
```

In my SQL query, I am trying to find average of CalibrationValueY where CalibrationValueX is a certain value:

```
SELECT avg(CalibrationValueY), MotorType, Motor FROM MotorTable
WHERE CalibrationValueX = 1.23333
GROUP BY MotorType
```

This will not return anything, since there is not a CalibrationValueX value that equals exactly 1.23333.

I am able to find closest match separately for each MotorTable with:

```
SELECT CalibrationValueY, FileSize, MotorType, Motor FROM MotorTable
where FileType = 'text' order by abs(FileSize - 1.23333) LIMIT 1
```

However, I can't get it to work with a group by statement.
How can I do it so that if I am grouping by MotorType and I am searching CalibrationValueX = 1.23333, I would get this:

```
A     Car       1.2343            2.33343
B     Boat      1.2455            2.55434
```

The solution with row_count and partition by does not work in sqlite3, as I realized.

```
with cte as (
    SELECT MotorType, CalibrationValueX, CalibrationValueY,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by MotorType order by abs(CalibrationValueX - 1.23333)) rn
    from historyCR
)
SELECT *
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Alternatively... I could just execute working code X types per each MotorType... Something like `SELECT DISTINCT MotorType FROM MotorTable` and run other query in a loop. However, I am concerned about speed.

Comment: Then why accept the answer? Edit the previous question to clarify that the answer doesn't work for your scenario.

Comment: I already set tag as sql-server. Valid answer, for sql-server.

Comment: If that's not what you're using - why?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe It would be bad form to change the scope of the question after it has been answered correctly.

Comment: @CL. I meant why tag it that in the first place; I reopened this and agree that a retrospective change is usually not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get all motor types:

   ```sql
   SELECT DISTINCT MotorType
   FROM MotorTable;
   ```
2. Get the motor with the nearest calibration value for each motor type:

   ```sql
   SELECT MotorType,
          (SELECT Motor
           FROM MotorTable AS T2
           WHERE T2.MotorType = Types.MotorType
           ORDER BY abs(CalibrationValueX - 1.2345)
           LIMIT 1
          ) AS Motor
   FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MotorType
         FROM MotorTable) AS Types;
   ```
3. Filter the original table with these values:

   ```sql
   SELECT Motor,
          MotorType,
          CalibrationValueX,
          CalibrationValueY
   FROM MotorTable
   JOIN (SELECT MotorType,
                (SELECT Motor
                 FROM MotorTable AS T2
                 WHERE T2.MotorType = Types.MotorType
                 ORDER BY abs(CalibrationValueX - 1.2345)
                 LIMIT 1
                ) AS Motor
         FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MotorType
               FROM MotorTable) AS Types)
   USING (MotorType, Motor);
   ```